# How to get values from unaligned memory in a standard way?

Tags: c++

I know C++11 has some standard facilities which would allow to get integral values from unaligned memory. How could something like this be written in a more standard way?

```
template <class R>
inline R get_unaligned_le(const unsigned char p[], const std::size_t s) {
    R r = 0;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < s; i++)
        r |= (*p++ & 0xff) << (i * 8); // take the first 8-bits of the char
    return r;
}
```

To take the values stored in litte-endian order, you can then write:

```
uint_least16_t value1 = get_unaligned_le<uint_least16_t > (&buffer[0], 2);
uint_least32_t value2 = get_unaligned_le<uint_least32_t > (&buffer[2], 4);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did the integral values get into the unaligned memory to begin with?
If they were `memcpy`ed in, then you can use `memcpy` to get them out.
If they were read from a file or the network, you have to know their
format: how they were written to begin with.  If they are four byte
big-endian 2s complement (the usual network format), then something
like:

```
//      Supposes native int is at least 32 bytes...
unsigned
getNetworkInt( unsigned char const* buffer )
{
    return buffer[0] << 24
        |  buffer[1] << 16
        |  buffer[2] <<  8
        |  buffer[3];
}
```

This will work for any unsigned type, provided the type you're aiming
for is at least as large as the type you input.  For signed, it depends
on just how portable you want to be.  If all of your potential target
machines are 2's complement, and will have an integral type with the
same size as your input type, then you can use exactly the same code as
above.  If your native machine is a 1's complement 36 bit machine (e.g.
a Unisys mainframe), and you're reading signed network format integers
(32 bit 2's complement), you'll need some additional logic.

Comment: Thanks. There are basically 8-bit-long unsigned chars which are being written from a device to the host machine. The device always writes them in little-endian order (I have fixed my question). Now one other thing that is not clear is the following: what happens if the bytes in host arch are longer than 8-bit? As an example, suppose they are 16-bit long. To write two 8-bit uchars, does the device consume two bytes in the host (where only the first 8-bit are significative) or does the device only use one byte?

Comment: @Martin It depends on what whoever wrote the code programmed, but logically, for anything which will be visible outside the machine, I'd expect only the lower order 8 bits of the bytes to be used.  (If you write the `int` by shifting and masking, then this falls out automatically from the code.  If the coder thought he'd be clever and used `memcpy`, then it's likely that every 8th bit will be missing in the final output.)

Answer (score 1):

As always, create the desired variable and populate it byte-wise:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename R>
R get(unsigned char * p, std::size_t len = sizeof(R))
{
    assert(len >= sizeof(R) && std::is_trivially_copyable<R>::value);

    R result;
    std::copy(p, p + sizeof(R), static_cast<unsigned char *>(&result));
    return result;
}
```

This only works universally for trivially copyable types, though you can probably use it for on-trivial types if you have additional guarantees from elsewhere.

Comment: isn't it static_assert(sizeof(R) >= len)... and std::copy(p, p + len... as I want to build the value from len bytes starting from p. I also added _le to my function name to underline the fact that it only works with litte-endian machines. I think it's the same here.

Comment: @Martin: It should be `_se` for "same endianness", if at all... but it should be clear that this doesn't let you serialize data persistently or cross-platformly.